# Encriptar y desencriptar con DES Java

Tags: java

tengo el problema de que cuando escribo lo que quiero encriptar en mi archivo de texto se "encripta de una forma rara" porque creo que se escribe la key y no el texto cifrado. Y cuando voy a descifrarlo para que se muestre en la consola el texto metido originalmente se muestra lo que supongo que es la key.

Esto es lo que sucede: 
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

No estoy entendiendo que demonios pasa en mi código

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String fich = "./ficheros/cifrador.txt", texto = "", string = "";
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    File fileEditar = new File(fich);
    if (!fileEditar.exists()) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Introduzca el texto:");
        texto = scan.next();
        
        
        // CIFRADOR
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");//GENERO LA KEY para DES
        SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey(); //GENERO LA KEY

        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); //ACTIVO CIFRADOR AES
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); //METO LA KEY EN EL CIFRADOR

        byte[] mensajeCifrado = desCipher.doFinal(texto.getBytes()); //LO CIFRO
        System.out.println("El mensaje cifrado es: " + new String(mensajeCifrado));
        
        Funciones.EscribirFichero(fich, mensajeCifrado, true);
        System.out.println("Fichero editado");
        
        // DESCIFRADOR
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] descifrar = desCipher.doFinal(mensajeCifrado);
        
        

      
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fich));  
     
        while ((string = br.readLine()) != null) 
        
        System.out.println("Texto descifrado: " + string); 
       
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva, tambien me toco hacer este ejercicio te entiendo. te lo dejo comentado. Puede que llegue tarde que nunca

```
public class CifrarConDES {

//Función para obtener selección de usuario en el menu
public static int getData() {
    Scanner entradaDeDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
    int seleccionUsuario = 0;
    seleccionUsuario = entradaDeDatos.nextInt();
    return seleccionUsuario;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Programa principal, cifra y descifra el contenido de un fichero utilizando una clave.

    int seleccionUsuario = 0;
    Scanner entradaDeDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombreArchivo = "";
    String rutaPrincipal = "./";
    Path rutaFinal;
    String contenidoFichero = "";
    String contenidoCifrado = "";
    File fichero;
    Cipher desCipher;
    byte[] lectura;
    byte[] mensajeCifrado;
    byte[] mensajeDescifrado;

    //Genero la key para el cifrado DES
    KeyGenerator keygen = null;
    try {
        keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();

    do {
        System.out.println("***Programa de cifrado***");
        System.out.println("Selecciona una opción:");
        System.out.println("    1.Cifrar");
        System.out.println("    2.Descifrar");
        System.out.println("    3.Salir");

        System.out.print("Opcion: ");
        try {
            seleccionUsuario = getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        switch (seleccionUsuario) {
            case 1:
                // Obtener nombre de fichero para cifrar
                System.out.print("Introduce el nombre del fichero para cifrar: ");
                nombreArchivo = entradaDeDatos.next();
                rutaFinal = Paths.get(rutaPrincipal + nombreArchivo);
                fichero = new File(rutaPrincipal + nombreArchivo);

                if (!fichero.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("El fichero no existe, volviendo al menu principal");
                    continue;
                } else if (!fichero.canRead()) {
                    System.out.println("No se puede leer el fichero, volviendo al menu principal");
                } else {
                    try {
                        // Leer el archivo y guardar sus datos en una cadena
                        lectura = Files.readAllBytes(rutaFinal); //Leer el contenido del fichero
                        System.out.println("El contenido del fichero para cifrar es: " + new String(lectura));

                        //Introducir la key en el cifrador
                        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

                        //Cifrar el contenido del fichero
                        mensajeCifrado = desCipher.doFinal(lectura);
                        System.out.println("El mensaje cifrado es: " + new String(mensajeCifrado));

                        // Guardar el contenido del fichero cifrado en un nuevo fichero
                        fichero = new File(rutaPrincipal + "CIFRADO_" + nombreArchivo);
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fichero, false);
                        fos.write(mensajeCifrado);
                        fos.close();
                        System.out.println("Fichero cifrado creado: " + rutaPrincipal + "CIFRADO_" + nombreArchivo);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // Obtener nombre de fichero para cifrar
                System.out.print("Introduce el nombre del fichero para descifrar: ");
                nombreArchivo = entradaDeDatos.next();
                rutaFinal = Paths.get(rutaPrincipal + nombreArchivo);
                fichero = new File(rutaPrincipal + nombreArchivo);

                if (!fichero.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("El fichero no existe, volviendo al menu principal");
                    continue;
                } else if (!fichero.canRead()) {
                    System.out.println("No se puede leer el fichero, volviendo al menu principal");
                } else {
                    try {
                        // Leer el archivo y guardar sus datos en una cadena
                        lectura = Files.readAllBytes(rutaFinal); //Leer el contenido del fichero
                        System.out.println("El contenido del fichero cifrado es: " + new String(lectura));

                        //Introducir la key en el cifrador
                        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

                        //Cifrar el contenido del fichero
                        mensajeDescifrado = desCipher.doFinal(lectura);
                        System.out.println("El mensaje original era: " + new String(mensajeDescifrado));

                        // Guardar el contenido del fichero cifrado en un nuevo fichero
                        fichero = new File(rutaPrincipal + "DESCIFRADO_" + nombreArchivo.substring(nombreArchivo.indexOf("_")));
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fichero, false);
                        fos.write(mensajeDescifrado);
                        fos.close();
                        System.out.println("Fichero cifrado creado: " + rutaPrincipal + "DESCIFRADO_" + nombreArchivo.substring(nombreArchivo.indexOf("_")));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Fin del programa");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Introduzca un valor válido");
                break;
        }
    } while (seleccionUsuario != 3);
```